# '[hidden]' selectors in css

Tags: html, css

When we view normalize.css http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ source code, we can see the following:

```
[hidden], template {
    display: none;
}
```

What is the meaning of [hidden] ?

Comment: @ShibinRagh The code is in the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[attribute]` is a selector for elements that have an attribute `attribute`.

`[hidden]` matches elements like this `<p hidden>Hidden paragraph</p>`.

The value doesn't matter, as long as the attribute exists. `[lang]` matches elements like this for example `<p lang="pt-br">Paragráfo</p>`.

P.S.: `[attribute=value]` also works. e.g. `[headers="numberHeader"]` for matching `<td headers="numberHeaders">...</td>`

Answer (score 0):

According to a fast google search, I found the following

```
/*
* Addresses styling for `hidden` attribute not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3,
* and Safari 4.
* Known issue: no IE 6 support.
*/

[hidden] {
display: none;
}
```

so obviously, you use the "hidden" attribute when you want something not to show up in your (e.g. html) code.